# AttributeError: type object 'Global' has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am getting below error while running the below database query in pyodbc.

**Query**

```
DECLARE  @TempTable Table (Flag int)
DECLARE @intFlag INT
DECLARE @intFlag1 VARCHAR(50);
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET @intFlag1 = 'foo'
SET @intFlag=(select a.fooID from foo a
where a.fooName=@intFlag1)
INSERT INTO @TempTable SELECT @intFlag
WHILE (@intFlag >=0)
BEGIN
 set @intFlag=(select a.basefooId from foo a
 join foo b on a.basefooId=b.fooID
 where a.fooID=@intFlag)
 INSERT INTO @TempTable SELECT @intFlag
 END
 SELECt * from @TempTable
```

The above query works fine in sql server.

**Database**

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(super().database_config())
        Global.connection = connection.cursor()  
result = list(Global.connection.execute(query))
```

**Error:**

```
while Global.cursor.nextset():  # NB: This always skips the first resultset
AttributeError: type object 'Global' has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Note: I am aware that, many of such questions are already asked and answered in the same forum but apparently my fix based on those guidance has not yielded expected results. May be I am wrong in implementing. Can someone throw a light as to how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved after keeping **SET NOCOUNT ON** on top of the query in pyodbc.